# Can't send email with Bulk Operation?

Tags: emails, views

*Drupal 6 site running on remote server.*

I created a **View** of the User type. Then I create a display to show all users of my site.
I set the Style of the display to **Bulk Operation** and in Selected operations I checked: `Send e-mail (system_send_email_action)`

In **Fields** I added the `User: E-mail E-mail` and other fields

Now I go to the path where I can see my users, I select one user (John) and click in `send email` under Bulk operation. I continue to complete a send the email and finally I get the message: `1 rows processed in about 23 ms:
Performed Send E-mail on user John.`

I understand that the email is sent to John user email from the administration site email.

But I don't receive the email. The email is not **really** sent.

I have a Webform node in my site which send email with no problems. So, I know there is nothing wrong with my server setting.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Don't know how it works exactly, but aren't those bulk emails sent by cron by any chance? If so, do you have cron running on your site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just given it a quick test with VBO 1.10, and as you said, emails are not being sent. Also, got "Cannot use %author token in this context." error in log.

See this issue - http://drupal.org/node/1003354 - "Can't sent email (or 'send tokenized email') on a user view. Reverting to 6.x-1.9 works" - seems that 1.9 should work better, or - if dev is acceptable to you - 6.x-1.x-dev

Or use Views Send instead (http://drupal.org/project/views_send)

Comment: thanks maciej, I tried both reverting VBO and using Views Send. Stil not working. I think that I'm not sending the user email properly. Can you take a look a this picture which shows how is set my view: [My view](http://img88.imageshack.us/img88/3255/viewcy.jpg)

Comment: And this is the error capture when using Views Send: [error when using Views Send](http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/4052/screenshot02m.jpg)